# Is the following true regarding the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $F(0)=0$ and $\dot{F}(0)=0$ then $F(t)=0$ for $t\ge 0$
where $\dot{F}(t)=\frac {d}{dt} F(t)$ and $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function on real numbers.

If it is not true what is the counter example and if it is true or true with some conditions what are the conditions and what is the proof?

Comment: Did you mean by chance that $\dot F(t)=0$ for all $t>0$ in the second assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Let F(t)=t^2 then F(0)=0^2 =0
F'(t)=2t then F'(0)=2.0=0

Answer (score 0):

There's a very straightforward counterexample - $F(t) = t^2$. Observe that $\frac{d}{dt}t^2 = 2t$, and $2 \cdot 0 = 0$; but obviously $t^2$ is not always zero.

The key is that while $\dot{F}(0) = 0$ means that, in the instant when $t = 0$, $F$ cannot change, it may be that $\dot{F}$ changes. In the example I gave above, $\dot{F}$ increases the instant $t$ rises above zero, and therefore allows $F$ to increase as well.